# Hello! Can you tell me if the verb "ouvrant" in the example below is in the present participle or gerund? Thank you!

Tags: grammaire

– Regarde, Dagobert, dirent les petites filles en souriant à leur tour, et *ouvrant* leurs yeux bleus de toute leur force.

"Le juif errant" - Eugène Sue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the missing *en*, it can be understood as a gerund with an implicit *en* dropped to avoid a repetition (*en souriant*, *en ouvrant*).

The three actions (speaking, smiling and opening wide the eyes) are clearly simultaneous.